# how to access foreignkey's attributes using django jQuery

Tags: jquery, django

How do I access a foreignkey's other attributes using django.jQuery. eg Suppose for a foreignKey teacher in the model Classroom, I wish to access the teacher's subject, qualification attributes in the django change_form.html for the model Classroom, for the selected teacher from the selected option of select tag?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has no direct access to the Django ORM. The only way to get more data about the particular selected value for a foreign key is to submit an AJAX request to a view that will return that data in a JSON response:

**views.py**

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest

def ajax_get_mymodel(request):
    id = request.GET.get('id')
    if id is not None:
        mymodel = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=id)
        data = serializers.serialize('json', [mymodel])
        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

**script.js**

```
$('#id_mymodel_field').change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON('/path/to/ajax/view/', { id: selected }, function (data, jqXHR) {
        // do something with `data`
    });
});
```